# How to implement media-type-versioning in NestJs?

Tags: routes, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

When using [media-type-versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design#media-type-versioning), different versions of an endpoint should have the same URL and the client can set the `Accept` header to the desired version: e.g.

```
Accept: application/vnd.adventure-works.v1+json
```

For version 2:

```
Accept: application/vnd.adventure-works.v2+json
```

Pseudo code for controller:

```js
    @Controller('orders')
    export class OrdersController {
    
      @Get('orders/:id')
      getOrdersV1(@Headers('Accept') acceptHeader: string) {
        // accept header must be 'application/vnd.adventure-works.v1+json'
        return {
          orderId: 1,
          orderName: 'Order 1'
        };
      }
    
      @Get('orders/:id')
      getOrdersV2(@Headers('Accept') acceptHeader: string) {
        // accept header must be 'application/vnd.adventure-works.v2+json'
        return {
          orderId: 1,
          name: 'Order 1'
        };
      }
```

- How can we implement this in NestJs?
  i.e. I need to somehow tell the NestJs router that the endpoint corresponding function should only be called when the accept-header has a fixed value:
- will this work with nestjs-swagger?

## Update

found a related feature request: [#3569](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/3569)

Answer (score 0):

you may try this:

```
  @Get('orders/:id')
  getOrders(@Headers('Accept') acceptHeader: string) {
    //Implement a manager class say OrderManager
    OrderManager orderManager = new OrderManager(); // Better to @Inject in constructor
    switch(acceptHeader) {
        case ''application/vnd.adventure-works.v1+json'':
            return orderManager.getOrdersV1();
        case ''application/vnd.adventure-works.v2+json'':
            return orderManager.getOrdersV2();
        default:
            // throw new InvalidInputException() if needed
            break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Well, this implementation works, but when we have only one method, how can we tell swagger (Open API) what types we return for each accept-header? i.e. which [nestjs-swagger-decorators](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/decorators) to use